# Sequencing in SCORM 1.2

Tags: scorm1.2

Does SCORM 1.2 have Sequencing? For example, is there a SCORM Engine that identifies which Activity should be delivered based on some sequencing information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCORM 1.2 allows you to define prerequisites for a given SCO, but that is the extent of the sequencing in SCORM 1.2. Note though that implementation of these prerequisites is optional for an LMS and the prerequisites definition and it isn't very widely adopted. For full sequencing you need to upgrade to SCORM 2004.